# Archiving S3 data to Glacier

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to move files from s3 to Glacier. This is my code

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
S3_BUCKET = 'bucket_name'
client = boto3.client('glacier')
bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)

def glacier():
    response = client.create_vault(
        vaultName='sample_vault')

    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        #downloading files from s3
        key = str(obj.key)
        print("key is ", key)
        data_stream = io.BytesIO()
        s3.meta.client.download_fileobj(S3_BUCKET, key,data_stream)
        print("downloaded file", data_stream)

        upload = client.upload_archive(
        vaultName='sample_vault',
        archiveDescription='string',
        body=data_stream
        )
        print("uploaded", key)
```

but I'm getting **InvalidParameterValueException** error.

```
[ERROR] InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UploadArchive operation: Invalid Content-Length: 0 Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 34, in lambda_handler
    upload = client.upload_archive(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Is this the correct method to use the **io.BytesIO()** method?. I also tried `bucket.download_file(S3_BUCKET,obj,'/tmp/'+key)` but got ValueError.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code seems to be attempting to copy all objects in an S3 bucket to Glacier. Did you consider simply applying a [lifecycle policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/) to the bucket?

Comment: Yes I understand that method but for some specific reasons I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two AWS services that make use of the word 'Glacier'.

1. There is the 'real' **Amazon Glacier** service that uses Vaults and Archives. It is slow, practically impossible to use, has almost no Management Console and is **more expensive** that the S3 option (below).
2. There are also the [Glacier Storage Classes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-class-intro.html#sc-glacier) available in Amazon S3. Objects can be uploaded to Amazon S3 using standard S3 API calls (eg AWS CLI) and the management console. These storage classes are **cheaper than Amazon Glacier**.

In short, **there is no sensible reason to use the 'old' Amazon Glacier anymore**. I recommend that you use the S3 Storage Classes instead.

As to your specific error: `Invalid Content-Length: 0`

It would appear that you are attempting to upload an archive to Glacier where that archive has a length of zero. This might be because the code is attempting to upload a zero-length object that was identifies a directory.

To explain: When the **Create folder** button is used in the Amazon S3 management console, a zero-length object is created with the same name as the directory (eg `invoices/`). This zero-length object 'forces' the directory to appear even though there are no objects in that path.

It is likely that you code is attempting to upload one of these zero-length objects to Glacier. To avoid this from happening, your code could skip-over any objects with a path that ends with a slash (`/`).

Comment: I tried that but still getting the same error. If I download files to data = io.BytesIO() after listing all from s3 bucket using bucket.objects.all() the files can be directly uploaded from the defined variable 'data' right? No need to process anything prior to upload?

Comment: You should skip-over any file that has a length of zero. You should be able to use `if len(data) > 0: upload`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error, its because you are reading the file from its end.

```js
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
S3_BUCKET = 'bucket_name'
client = boto3.client('glacier')
bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)

def glacier():
    response = client.create_vault(
        vaultName='sample_vault')

    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        #downloading files from s3
        key = str(obj.key)
        print("key is ", key)
        data_stream = io.BytesIO()
        s3.meta.client.download_fileobj(S3_BUCKET, key,data_stream)
        print("downloaded file", data_stream)
        data_stream.seek(0)  #take pointer back to zero before uploading
        upload = client.upload_archive(
        vaultName='sample_vault',
        archiveDescription='string',
        body=data_stream
        )
        print("uploaded", key)
`
```